# CodeIgniter 4 Class not Found, problem with Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, codeigniter-4

I tried to create a Helper in CodeIgniter 4 but I can't get it loaded.
I tried the following, but to no effort. I'm new to CodeIgniter 4 and namespaces so I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't find what. What could be wrong?
When running I get an Error:
**Error
Class 'App\Helpers\php2jquery' not found**
Thanks for any help.
Edward

This is the controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Helpers\php2jquery;
class Test extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        
        $param = “”; //Doesn’t matter here ;
        
        $jqueryparam = New php2jquery();
    
        $data[‘jqueryobject’] = $jqueryparam->php_array_to_jquery_param($param, 4, "new FWDRAP", "FWDRAPUtils.onReady(function(){" );
        
        $data['base'] = config('App')->baseURL;
        return view('test_message',$data);
    }

    

}
```

and this is the Helper in App/Helpers/php2jquery
(I also tried php2jquery_helper)

```
<?php
    class php2jquery
    {
        
        function php_array_to_jquery_param($param,$indent=0, $object="", $wrapfunction=""){
            Return (“this is a test”); //Dummy
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you never defined a namespace in that `php2jquery` class file

Comment: Thanks, that's the one I missed.

Answer (score 0):

in App/Helpers/php2jquery set namespace
and try in controller wite "app\Helpers" with small letter

Comment: I upvoted you. This helped me very much.